# build flat array of objects from tree object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tree

I'm struggling with converting nested object to needed format. I want an array containing objects from nested object to suit table data format. Here are links for
[format example](https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/blob/main/docs/public/data/users-merge-cells.json) and [table i want](https://rsuitejs.com/components/table/#rowspan)

```
const data = [
    [
        "team",
        "year",
        "product",
        "downTime",
        "totalCount"
    ],
    {
        "metrics": [
            24965836704,
            25161192
        ],
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "UNDEFINED",
                "metrics": [
                    14697807552,
                    6858384
                ],
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "2021",
                        "metrics": [
                            14697807552,
                            6858384
                        ],
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "UNDEFINED",
                                "metrics": [
                                    null,
                                    null
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "cola",
                                "metrics": [
                                    14697807552,
                                    6858384
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...another object just like above
        ]
    }
]
```

In short I want this piece of **data** above to be in form of like:

```
[
  { team: 'UNDEFINED', year: '2021', product: 'cola', downTime: 14697807552, totalCount: 6858384},
  { team: 'UNDEFINED', year: '2021', product: 'cola', downTime: 14697807552, totalCount: 6858384},
  ...
];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: here is what i have tried: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3xssuugmn

Comment: please add all relevant information to the question. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz updated post, if still not understandable let me know. Also, link in my first comment is what I've tried.

Comment: where do you get the two last values for `downTime` and `totalCount` from? is this value always the same as at the first level?

Comment: @NinaScholz these values are derived from `metrics` array, in this example metrics[0] = downTime and metrics[1] = totalCount.

Comment: No it is not same as first level, each field has its own values. for example, for team `UNDEFINED` its `totalCount` and `downTime` are 14697807552 and 6858384, respectively.

Comment: I don't get it. Your input has `null` and `25161192`, but that doesn't occur in your output. Can you clarify? Could you also make your input example to have unique values, instead of so many duplicates? It is currently hard to see which value goes where.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, issue has been solved. Sorry for those who didn't understand my question, next time I'll do better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you. it take the metrics from the final level.

```js
const
    getFlat = (array, keys, level = 0) => array.flatMap(o => {
        const
            q = { [keys[level]]: o.name },
            m = Object.fromEntries(keys.slice(-2).map((k, i) => [k, o.metrics[i]]));

        return o.children
            ? getFlat(o.children, keys, level + 1).map(p => ({ ...q, ...p }))
            : { ...q, ...m };
    }),
    data = [["team", "year", "product", "downTime", "totalCount"], { metrics: [24965836704, 25161192], children: [{ name: "UNDEFINED", metrics: [14697807552, 6858384], children: [{ name: "2021", metrics: [14697807552, 6858384], children: [{ name: "UNDEFINED", metrics: [null, null] }, { name: "cola", metrics: [14697807552, 6858384] }] }] }] }],
    [keys, { children: array }] = data,
    result = getFlat(array, keys, 0);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```